# Is there an easy solution to export a filtered backendlist

Tags: list, filter, widget, octobercms

I have a list with products and locations. I've created a filterdefinition and can filter products based on a location. 
Now I want to export te filtered selection to print it to an pdf.

I've tried to acces the filtered items with the ajax framework, but can't find any information on how to retrieve the filtered id's.

My printhandler works fine, I only need to get the ID's of selected items in the filter.

scopes:

```
location:
    label: Location
    modelClass: XXX\xxxx\Models\Location
    conditions: location_id in (:filtered)
    nameFrom: location
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, found a solution after asking for one;

Found a piece of code:

```
function getCurrentFilters() {
        $filters = [];
        foreach (\Session::get('widget', []) as $name => $item) {
            if (str_contains($name, 'Filter')) {
                $filter = @unserialize(@base64_decode($item));
                if ($filter) {
                    //$filters[] = $filter;
                    array_push($filters, $filter);
                }
            }
        }

        return $filters;
    }
```